# Hard drives indication with controller MegaRAID SAS 9261-8i on HP Proliant DL320e Gen8. Is it possible?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, hp, hp-proliant, hardware-raid

Give me advice, please.

My situation: 
There're the server HP ProLiant DL320e Gen8 and MegaRAID SAS 9261-8i RAID Controller.

I installed Controller into server and I reconnected Mini-SAS cord from block of hard drives to controller, but I haven't any indication of hard discs on server front panel.

I can see indication of drives activity only during server boot.

Controller has 2-pin connector (JT6B3, SAS Activity LED header) but where and how can I connect it?

Thanx.

Comment: Why are you using an LSI RAID controller instead of the HP Smart Array controller on this server?

Comment: Becouse in DL320e Gen8 HP Smart Array controller is "software" controller in fact :(

"There are no "hardware accelerated" raid features on the b-series "smart array" controllers...

--craig, HP ISS Linux R&D"
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-certification/+question/214703

Comment: Use a higher end HP Smart Array controller.

Comment: And I can't use my LSI controller for my case?

Comment: Technically, you should be able to use an LSI controller, but it's likely not a supported setup. HP ProLiant Gen8 servers are not friendly to third-path components.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest that you try this with an HP Smart Array controller. HP went [out of their way](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYYRAB17f4s) to develop their SmartDrive technology and new drive carriers for the ProLiant Gen8 product line.

See: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1hOYjqRvSQ

Other controllers simply wouldn't be aware of the new drive indicators. Note the additional electrical contacts on the backplane side of the drive tray? Your LSI RAID controller would not be able to interface with those.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Adaptec card running just fine with the HP DL320e and the new trays. It does show the drives working, but of course not any of the other led indications. But I am having some trouble right now to swap the standard cable for a longer one to the backplane... so maybe there is something going on there... but not sure what that would be... looks like a regular 8087 cable.